# Limit amount of Map in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am making a game and will use hazelcast to save player data, should I save each player's data as a Map? Because if I save player's data as a map element, so with every small change like increasing the gold value, I have to put all of the data of the player:
ex:

```
playerData.gold = newValue;
players.replace(palyerID, playerData);
```

but if I make a player data as a Map, so I will just put new gold value. ex:

```
playerA.replace("gold", newGoldValue)
```

But I affair that creates many maps is not good (in case I have more than 1 million players). Can I create as many maps as I want? if not, how many maps can I create?

Answer (score 0):

Hoang

I just answered the same question in our community channel:

You can use EntryProcessor to read or update only a single for some of the properties of the player data. I dont know how many users you’ll have but in case you have 100k user, for example, creating 100K map wont help you, but you can have 100K or tens of millions or more records on a single map. Please check: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.4/manual/html-single/index.html#entry-processor and https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/entry-processor

On the other hand, if each user data > 5-10 MB & if you need to access all of that data frequently, then splitting it is a good idea.

Please note that these are just general suggestions. You need to test different setups & find the most suitable & performant one for your use case.